# How to update a particular row in realm table android

Tags: android, realm

I have the following table with a `PrimaryKey` in it. I have inserted some values in the table. Now I need to update a particular value in a particular row. I have a row with `gameType` as `Puzzle` and I need to update the `currentLevel` in the row. But I am not able to achieve that.

`GamesDetails` table:

```
public class GamesDetail extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String gameType;
    private int currentLevel;
    private int totalLevel;
    private int totalCoins;
    private int currentBadge;

    public String getGameType() {
        return gameType;
    }

    public void setGameType(String gameType) {
        this.gameType = gameType;
    }

    public int getCurrentLevel() {
        return currentLevel;
    }

    public void setCurrentLevel(int currentLevel) {
        this.currentLevel = currentLevel;
    }

    public int getTotalLevel() {
        return totalLevel;
    }

    public void setTotalLevel(int totalLevel) {
        this.totalLevel = totalLevel;
    }

    public int getTotalCoins() {
        return totalCoins;
    }

    public void setTotalCoins(int totalCoins) {
        this.totalCoins = totalCoins;
    }

    public int getCurrentBadge() {
        return currentBadge;
    }

    public void setCurrentBadge(int currentBadge) {
        this.currentBadge = currentBadge;
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried to update a particular row in the table:

```
final GamesDetail puzzleGameDetail = realm.where(GamesDetail.class).equalTo("gameType","Puzzle").findFirst();
                    final int[] nextLevel = {puzzleGameDetail.getCurrentLevel()};

                    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            puzzleGameDetail.setCurrentLevel(++nextLevel[0]);
                            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(puzzleGameDetail);
                        }
                    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Done");
                        }
                    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable error) {
                            Log.e(TAG,error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
```

But the value is not getting updated and I am getting this following error:

`Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.`

How can I update a particular value in a particular row in the table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `executeTransactionAsync`, the `execute` block will run in a background thread, any Realm objects access from that thread need to be created/queried on that thread from the Realm instance which is the param of `execute`.

Move your finding `GamesDetail` query inside `execute` block and rest will work fine.